# Processing rotate triangle on keyboard event

Tags: rotation, processing

I want to rotate my triangle

My code not working in all cases.

It is working only in this case

```java
triangle ( - 10, + 26, 0, -25, + 10, + 26);
```

So when I click to UP, Down, Left and Right keys I should rotate my triangle on appropriate position.

I am not sure this is the best way but I do like this so far

Here is the code

```java
  float X1 = 200;
  float Y1 = 200;

  float X2 = 220;
  float Y2 = 160;

  float X3 = 240;
  float Y3 = 200; 

void setup() {
  background(2);
  size(400, 400);

}

void draw() {

  background(0);


  // background (0); 
  smooth();
  fill(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2); 
  rotate(radians(angle)); 
  triangle ( X1, Y1,  X2, Y2, X3, Y3);

  //triangle ( - 10, + 26, 0, -25, + 10, + 26); This code works

}


int angle = 0;
void keyPressed() {


  switch (keyCode)
  {
    case UP:

    angle +=90;

      break;
    case DOWN:

     angle +=180;

      break;
    case LEFT:

     angle +=90;

      break;
    case RIGHT:

       angle +=-90;

      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the coordinates you're using.

First off, you're translating to the center of the screen. That means that your coordinates will all be relative to that position instead of to the upper-left corner of the screen.

That's why your variables don't work. It looks like they're relative to the upper-left corner of the screen, not the center of the screen.

To fix your problem, you're going to have to redefine your variables so that they're relative to the center of the screen.

Think about it this way: you're translating to the center of the screen, which means your new origin is at `200,200`. Then you draw a point at `200,200`. But that point is relative to the center of the screen, so you're really drawing it at `400,400`, which is off the edge of your window. That's why you can't see it. You really should be drawing it at `0,0`, which will show up as `200,200` since you've translated there already.

Comment: I am very new in Processing. Could please give me an example?

Comment: Do you mean translate(0, 0 ); ? Please give example with code

Comment: @ggdev You're translating to the center of the screen using this line of code: `translate(width/2, height/2); ` What example code are you asking for? I've explained what the problem is. What about it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: If my code is not working that mean there is a mistake in the code. It is obvious. So just to know translate line is wrong won't help me to finish what I need. Like I told I am very new in processing. I just need to finish this assignment today.

Comment: @ggdev I've explained what your mistake is. Stack Overflow isn't a homework service, and we can't just do your homework for you. Please try to understand what I've said, and if there's something you don't understand, then ask about it. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I understand what is wrong with translate line, but I still can not find a solution.

Comment: @ggdev Now that you understand the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: I just removed translate. I should change the coordinates but I don't know what concept I should use

Comment: @ggdev Why did you remove translate? You need it for your rotations to work. Did you write this code?

Comment: @ Kevin Workman yes I got it from google. Actually, understand how it drawing triangle but I want to understand the formula. Please give me a detailed explanation.

Comment: @ggdev That really isn't how Stack Overflow works. You can't just copy paste code without understanding it and expect it to work. I'd be happy to help, but you have to make an attempt at understanding the code first. Do you understand what the `translate()` function is doing? If not, please consult the documentation and maybe put together a couple smaller example programs for yourself first.

Comment: Thank you for your help but your answers are not clear. So I will try to continue my research!

Comment: @ggdev I think if you took the time to understand your own code first, and then took the time to understand my answer, it would become clear. You can't just keep copy pasting and hope for the best. That's not how programming works, and you're setting yourself up for a ton of headaches. You really need to understand what your code is doing first. Do you understand what the `translate()` function is doing?